# Powershell if get-service

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I am writing a inventory script to gather some information from a list of server and im trying to put a section in which checks for a service, if the service is running it populates a cell in an excel document with "Installed" and if the service is not present "Not installed".

Now the code below works perfectly for servers it can contact but if it tries to run against a server that is not replying it populates the cell with "Installed".

Any suggestions?

```
if (Get-Service "ConfigMgr Task Sequence Agent" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
{$Sheet1.Cells.Item($intRowNet, 41) = "Installed"} 
else
{$Sheet1.Cells.Item($intRowNet, 41) = "Not installed"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Switch your ErrorAction to 'Stop', and use a Try/Catch to handle the ones that fail:

```
Try{
  if (Get-Service "ConfigMgr Task Sequence Agent" -ErrorAction Stop)
    {$Sheet1.Cells.Item($intRowNet, 41) = "Installed"} 
     else
     {$Sheet1.Cells.Item($intRowNet, 41) = "Not installed"} 
    }

 Catch {
         $Sheet1.Cells.Item($intRowNet, 41) = "Query failed"
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but exactly the same happens with the above code :(

Answer (score 0):

Before you run the `Get-Service` you can do a `Test-Connection`.

```
if(!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $server -Count 1 -Quiet)){
    'Cannot Communicate'
    continue
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this script is set to loop through a list of servers from a text file and I don't want it to bomb out when it reaches one that it cannot talk to I want it to continue down the list.